# What do first terms in Fourier expansion of a function mean?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, approximation

If in the Fourier expansion of a function, only the first terms are important and one can ignore higher terms (for example as below), what does it meana and what can one say about the function $f$(\theta)?

$f(\theta) \simeq a \sin(\theta) + b \sin(2\theta) + c \sin(3\theta)$

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? If the fourier series has finitely many terms, that means your function can be written as a finite linear combination of $\sin(k\theta)$. There isn't much else to say...

Comment: what does higher terms (larger $k$ s in $\sin (k \theta)$ ) in a Fourier expansion mean? @AlexR.

Comment: Sometimes circuit designers will call the zero'th term the "DC term" and musicians will sometimes call the one'th term the "fundamental harmonic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Importance" depends on the application. For "well-behaved" functions $g$ (for example $g \in L^2$) the magnitude of the coefficients eventually has to drop, that is why you can in practical applications ignore the higher order terms, where the highest order to be considered depends on your application's required precision.

Having said that, it should be clear that the "lower order" terms, that is the terms not to be ignored, do not have any "special" interpretation that distinguishes them from the "ignored" terms, as the only criterion for the selection of the maximum order considered is the required precision.

The only exception here is the first coefficient, which represents the average value of the function $g$, but that is so in general and has nothing to do with which coefficients / terms are ignored.